# Error 500 with pg_connect in PHP on windows subsystem debian (WSL)

Tags: php, postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run a simple PHP code for connect to a postgres database, on a debian subsystem in windows (WSL). PHP 7.3.19 .

```
<?php
    echo 'Connection test : ';
    $connection = pg_connect ("host=localhost dbname=site user=postgres password=root");
    if($connection) {
       echo 'connected';
    } else {
        echo 'there has been an error connecting';
    } 
?>
```

but the only result I have is 'Connection test : ' and an internal server error (500). Why ?

Answer (score 0):

My php-pgsql version was not fine, so I've just install the good version :

```
sudo apt install php7.3-pgsql
```